# I just bought a old 96 saturn and it has black oil

Tags: saturn

My car won't start in the morning or after it sits awhile. It also clunks when going into reverse from park but not from drive.

What I was told is that the idle is high and flooding the engine in the morning or when it sits awhile, and that the idle being high is the cause of the clunk. I was also told to put heavier oil, 15w40, because I need a rebuild kit for my motor.

I think that it could be a clogged fuel filter and that it needs an oil change. I don't know. Could I get some advice? It's also missing on cylinders 1 and 4.

Comment: I ment the trany doesn't clunk when going from drive to revers

Comment: Please use punctuations and proper english.Your question is difficult to understand

Answer (score 1):

I would give the whole car an overhaul. Change the air and fuel filters, change the spark plugs, change the transmission fluid, change the coolant, change the brake fluid. The car is 21 years-old and who knows how it was maintained in the past.

After all of that, you'll have a happier car and probably a better idea of what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking the clunk is a motor mount.

If the oil is black, change it.  Use the manufacturer recommended oil (likely 5W-30 or 10W30) unless it is causing issues, like the oil pressure being too low.

If it is missing on 1 and 4, I would deal with those issues first.  It's either going to be spark or fuel causing the miss, so injector cleaner, plugs, wires, cap, rotor.

It is normal for the idle to be higher (up to 2000 RPM) when the engine is cold.  This helps it start and warm up.